# What OS X software do I need to produce a video like this

Tags: macos, video, software-rec, screencasts

Watch [this video](http://www.khanacademy.org/video/iit-jee-trigonometry-problem-1?playlist=IIT%20JEE%20Questions).

What I like is the ease with which user is able to write or draw anything. Also I like the way he is able to use different colors.

I have a Mac and I would like to produce a videos for my clients.

What software do I need?

Answer (score 1):

This could be recorded with **Quicktime X**'s Screen Capture functionality (built-in to OS X 10.6), while drawing on a document in any **image editor with a brush tool and color palette** (ex. Photoshop). The author appears to be scrolling down the document during the lesson. After recording, you could then edit the film in **iMovie** if necessary (for example, to crop the color palette and other UI from view in the video.)

I think the key here for the ease of writing and drawing is that the author is using a [graphics tablet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_tablet) (a popular example of this is a [Wacom](http://www.wacom.com/) tablet.) Check [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_12?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=wacom%20bamboo) for some good pricing.

Comment: The author clearly moves the pointer out of the visible canvas to select different colors and to scroll down, so a large black "blackboard" image onto which he pasted the math problem at the top seems plausible.

Comment: Also, when he erases something he's written, that's likely just the *Undo* command of the program he's using.